# How can I get the real size of drawable in android?

Tags: android, size, drawable, pixel

hi there I have an `ImageView` that contains a `Drawable` , I want to know the real size of this `Drawable` ( width and height ) . how can I get the real size please?

I tried that but its not working:

```
final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePlan);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gratuit);
System.out.println("w=="+img.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()+" h=="+img.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight());
```

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you have to convert drawable into bitmap then you can get image height and width.

try below code:-

```
BitmapDrawable bd=(BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(imageID); 
double imageHeight = bd.getBitmap().getHeight(); 
double imageWidth = bd.getBitmap().getWidth();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inTargetDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.sample_image, options);
int w = bmp.getWidth();
int h = bmp.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting zero for both width and height, because, the drawable has not been you measured,

```
img.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("w=="+img.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()+" h=="+img.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight());

     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By decoding resource into bitmap you can get the real width and height..

```
    final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gratuit);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of VectorDrawable
you can use `intrinsicHeight` and `intrinsicWidth`

So the accepted answer will be

```
  val vd = this.resources.getDrawable(cardInput.card!!.brand.icon) as VectorDrawable
            val imageHeight = vd.intrinsicHeight
            val imageWidth = vd.intrinsicWidth
```